# Issue with text overflow for mobile and small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to optimise my website for mobiles and small screens. The website looks perfect on anything 1920x1080 and above. I'm using bootstrap and I can't figure out what's wrong with my code that is preventing the mobile scaling from working.

It seems my background 's arent scaling to the text - that is, these 's appear to be completely static and the text can just overflow past them and stack onto other parts of the page. What I want to happen is for the background colour, (white, grey, dark grey) to extend to the regions of the text on the mobile view.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every div you height and % (percentage). Take all those out and your site will be ok.

I also noticed the carousel is very slow at loading the pictures. If you compress each to about 200k or less it will load faster and still keep the resolution ok.

you have a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">`

i suggest making this to `.8` or `.9` or `1`

the navbar menu does not adapt to mobile screens. Check the link below to see how a boostrap nav menu should be like and follow the example to create one

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

[image]

Sections like these should have the same amount of text. So shorten the middle one out a bit, but make all sections equal to the amount of text and lines (example 3 lines or 4 lines of text) so they are responsive. A workaround will be to give a min-height to a section but i dont recomend doing that

Also the heading learning and problem solving is too long. You can change that to Learning

[image]

Comment: How can I remove the percentages of the height and width properties? If i define them via pixels, the same issue will occur. I've adapted the navbar to disappear on mobile devices.

Comment: @Zaidra do you see in my answer (.music) you gave (height:75%). Take that out. Bootstrap is allwready set to be responvive. You will see those Heights in (mywork, myskills, about, footer) divs. Every section you have something check and take out the height. Thats whats screwing things up

Comment: @Zaidra ive already done a test on browser and mobile. Looks very good. The Nav menu need sorting out so use the recommends from bootstrap to make it responsive. Other than that the carousel pics load veryslow, so compress the pics as small as possible while keeping the resolution ok

Comment: @humble.rumble it took me 20secs to track down the issues. He did provide a website

Comment: @humble.rumble No need to get angsty. I've been researching this all day, and only now came to stack as a last resort at 10 in the evening with a massive headache and a tired mind. This an issue pertaining to bootstrap and SOMETHING that I have done to over-ride its reponsiveness in my code - of which I have no clue.

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou Thank you, this is a good solution for now. I'm going to look into these issues more in depth as there are still many problems when viewing on my 13" laptop screen as opposed to my 1920x1080 monitor.

Comment: @Zaidra no probs. There will be some issues for sure, but should be very easy to track down. Once you get those sorted out, if you get stuck again, post a new question or contact me

Answer (score 0):

use the viewport meta tag, put it in your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For font sizes, i prefer to use vh(viewport height) & vw(viewport width) to control sizes.  That way the size will be proportional to the device view.

Be wary though.  the viewport tag may cause rendering issues with height.  For this, i use vh.

also, if the page is meant to fit to the screen, it may be a good idea to use "user-scalable=no" in your viewport tag.  But only do that if you wish for end users to not zoom in & out.

Comment: weary vs wary... i can't believe i mixed those up... *facepalm*